# Device-located array of pixels (from C++ AMP) to a window using D3D / D2D

Tags: c++, direct3d, c++-amp

I have a `concurrency::array` (C++ AMP) of colors on device holding colors for each pixel.

I would like to feed this array to Direct3D so it would be used as a buffer to display in a window without having to copy the data to the host.

I also tried using `concurrency::direct3d::make_array`, which associates an `ID3D11Buffer` with an `accelerator_view`, but I don't know how to then take this array and feed it to the Direct3D as the source of an image displayed in a window.

Alternatively, I could convert this data into a texture.

So the basic question is: *Given a chunk of color information for each pixel located on a device, how to feed them to Direct3D to be used as a screen buffer of sorts?* (This chunk just happens to be computed by C++ AMP.)

Comment: Can you use `concurrency::graphics::texture` instead of `concurrency::array`?

Comment: @Drop I could, but they seem to be size restricted, is there a way to create multiple of these and "fold" an image from them?

Comment: This is strange, because `concurrency::graphics::texture<T, N>` allows dimensions up to 16536 x 16536 texels for 2D and 2048 x 2048 x 2048 for 3D. You must initialize it like this (in 2D case): `concurrency::graphics::texture<float_4, 2> (1920, 1024);` (dimensions in texels, no need to multiply by 4). What debug info says?

Comment: @Drop Mmmm, it works with a 2d texture like so: `texture<float_4, 2> tex3(1920, 1200);`, I tried 1 dimension like so: `texture<float_4, 1> tex4(1920 * 1200);` and it failed :). Well, thanks, so yes, I indeed CAN use a texture! Any idea as to what the best way to spit it out to the screen is now?

Comment: Yeah, single dimension of 1D and 2D textures limited to 16536 texels. As of rendering, fastest way is to draw a simple sprite: quad (two triangles that form rectangle) with texture over it, or you can use [DirectXTK](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SpriteBatch&referringTitle=DirectXTK) which is known as unofficial replacement of D3DX (latter is deprecated now). There are simpler but slower ways such as GDI.

Comment: @Drop but is it possible to hook it up from the device (out of AMP) without having to copy it back to the host and back again? (using the DirectXTK thing)

Comment: Finally, I've added an answer. Hope I didn't forgot anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Texture

So, as we discussed in comments, you can work with 2D textures:

```
concurrency::graphics::texture<float_4, 2> tex(1920, 1200);
```

---

#### Device, then accelerator

Then, to proceed with DirectX 11,  you must have [`ID3D11Device`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ID3D11DeviceContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is better to create `ID3D11Device` and `ID3D11DeviceContext` by hand, and then create [`accelerator_view`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Library/hh350919) object based on your device. Example code from Julia2D sample:

```
accelerator_view av=concurrency::direct3d::create_accelerator_view(g_pd3dDevice);
texture<unorm4, 2> tex = make_texture<unorm4, 2>(av, pTexture);
```

---

#### Accelerator, then device

Alternatively, you can get pointers to `ID3D11Device` and `ID3D11DeviceContext` from your existing[`accelerator_view`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Library/hh350919) object:

- you use [`concurrency::direct3d::get_device()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/hh350911) function:

  ```
  IUnknown* unknown = concurrency::direct3d::get_device(accelerator);
  ```
- on returned [`IUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, you call [`IUnknown::QueryInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to cast it to `ID3D11Device`

  ```
  ID3D11Device* device = 0;
  unknown->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Device), &device));
  ```
- then you get `ID3D11DeviceContext` calling [`ID3D11Device::GetImmediateContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

  ```
  ID3D11DeviceContext* context = 0;
  device->GetImmediateContext(context);
  ```

---

#### Finally, rendering

With `ID3D11Device` and `ID3D11DeviceContext` you can proceed to rendering (example with [DirectXTK](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SpriteBatch&referringTitle=DirectXTK)):

```
SpriteBatch* spriteBatch(new SpriteBatch(context));

spriteBatch->Begin();
spriteBatch->Draw(texture, XMFLOAT2(x, y));
spriteBatch->End();
```

---

Also, I've found this two samples involved C++Amp/DirectX interop, that can be useful for you: [one](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Image-Effects-sample-in-C-77db1745), [two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/09/25/julia-fractal-using-c-amp.aspx).

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Changed the question to reflect the comments a bit, thanks, very helpful! :)

Comment: Btw, julia thing is VERY useful, albeit after seeing stuff like `bool selfshadow = mc.selfShadow == 0  ? false : true;` makes one wonder whether the interop is done properly ^^.